# Checkbox value not saving in Woocommerce cart and checkout

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having a problem with saving custom checkbox value in woocommerce cart and checkout.

I've added custom checkbox to checkout shipping table that adds custom bag if certain shipping method is selected. If checkbox is checked and I choose other shipping method and then return to a certain one with checkbox, checkbox is unchecked on ajax reload of cart summary.

I tried to save checkbox value in cookies with something like this

```
var checkbox = $('#your-form :checkbox:first'),
    checkboxCookieName = 'checkbox-state';

checkbox.prop('checked', +$.cookie(checkboxCookieName));

checkbox.click(function() {
   $.cookie(checkboxCookieName, +this.checked);
});
```

But it didn't work.

Code for checkbox:

```
function my_custom_checkout_field() {
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0]; 
    if ($chosen_shipping == 'nova_poshta_shipping_method') { 
    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field">';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'checked'      => 'checked',
        'class'     => array('input-checkbox'),
        'label'     => __('<span class="paperbagspan">Добавить фирменный пакет <img class="paperbag" src="https://paradisefruit.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/paper-bag.png" style="width:30px"><img class="paperbagpink" style="display:none; width:30px" src="https://paradisefruit.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/paper-bag-pink.png" ></span>'),
    ),  WC()->checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ) );
    echo '</div>';
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', 'checkout_shipping_additional_field', 20, 2 );
function checkout_shipping_additional_field( $method, $index )
{
    if( $method->get_id() == 'nova_poshta_shipping_method' ){
       return my_custom_checkout_field();
    }
}


// Save the custom checkout field in the order meta, when checkbox has been checked
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['my_field_name'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'my_field_name', sanitize_text_field($_POST['my_field_name'] ));
}
```

What am I doing wrong or is there some wordpress fuction that saves custom field values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood correctly -- i.e. you have a checkbox and on every input, the value is stored in a cookie. On page load, you pull the cookie value and set it to the checkbox. Everything works well, except for when you do an AJAX request and load the whole thing.

This seems like it's more of a javascript issue (rather than PHP).

On page load you already marking the checkbox as selected based on the cookie value. However, when you do the AJAX request, you pull the checkbox and the javascript code that is responsible with setting the checkbox value isn't called anymore
 ( i.e. checkbox.prop('checked', +$.cookie(checkboxCookieName)) ).

What you need to do is to call:

```
checkbox.prop('checked', +$.cookie(checkboxCookieName));
```

on finishing the ajax request and AFTER injecting the HTML

Woocommerce has these three events:

updated_wc_div
updated_cart_totals
updated_shipping_method

I do not fully grasp what you're trying to do, but you must hook your code to one of this depending on your needs.
The way to do it is (e.g. using updated_cart_totals) :

```
$(document).on('updated_cart_totals', function(){
    checkbox.prop('checked', +$.cookie(checkboxCookieName));
});
```

Hope it's useful.

Comment: should i put it in Woocommerce checkout.js? Or make separate ajax call in custom js file?

Comment: It's not recommended to edit the source files as you'll lose your changes on every update.
Woocommerce JS triggers events at certain points, so you need to hook your action to that hook. However, I do not fully grasp what you are trying to do, so I can't suggest you to use any events.



Or you could look into PHP cookies and setting the value straight from PHP.